# How to Get Uploaded Files' tmp_name in a Form?

Tags: php, html, forms, file, upload

I am creating a form where users can upload at most 4 pictures and change the uploaded pictures. Pictures are uploaded to the folder **upload/**.

If any picture already exists in the folder, the form will show the existing picture so that the user can check whether to change the picture or not.

HTML & PHP codes are as below:

```html
     <form name="upload_form" action="upload.php">
      <div id="upload_block0" class="upload_block" style="margin: 1rem;">
         <?php 
         if( file_exists("upload/pic0.jpg")){
           echo "<img src='upload/pic0.jpg'>";
         }
         ?>
         <input type="file" name="picture[]" id="picture" />
         <button onclick="removeBlock()">Remove</button>
      </div>

      <div id="upload_block1" class="upload_block" style="margin: 1rem;">
         <?php 
         if( file_exists("upload/pic1.jpg")){
           echo "<img src='upload/pic1.jpg'>";
         }
         ?>
        <input type="file" name="picture[]" id="picture" />
        <button onclick="removeBlock()">Remove</button>
      </div>

      <div id="upload_block2" class="upload_block" style="margin: 1rem;">
        <?php 
         if( file_exists("upload/pic2.jpg")){
           echo "<img src='upload/pic2.jpg'>";
         }
         ?>
        <input type="file" name="picture[]" id="picture" />
        <button onclick="removeBlock()">Remove</button>
      </div>

      <div id="upload_block3" class="upload_block" style="margin: 1rem;">
        <?php 
         if( file_exists("upload/pic3.jpg")){
           echo "<img src='upload/pic3.jpg'>";
         }
         ?>
        <input type="file" name="picture[]" id="picture" />
        <button onclick="removeBlock()">Remove</button>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" />

      <button onclick="addBlock()">Upload More</button>

    </form>
```

```
<?php  //upload.php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["picture"]["name"]); $i++) {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"][$i], "upload/pic".$i
}
?>
```

If users don't want the old picture, they can click `<input type="file">` to upload a new picture;

If they still want the old one, how can I let `<input type="file">` get the existing picture's tmp_name so that the **upload.php** can upload the picture?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I don't get you answer, Can you  tell me more about what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore the `move_uploaded_file()` when no uploaded files

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["picture"]["name"]); $i++) {
  if ($_FILES["picture"]['size'] > 0 && $_FILES['picture']['error'] == 0) {
      // upload file when there are uploaded file
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'][$i], 'upload/pic' . $i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Because I will make the form dynamically, so I still need to find a way to get the tmp_name. For example, if there are only 2 uploaded pictures in the folder, it will show only two <div id="upload_block">. Once the users want to upload more photo, they can click <button onclick="addBlock()"> to add more <div id="upload_block"> to upload pictures; Once they want to remove photo, they could click <button onclick="RemoveBlock()"> to remove <div id="upload_block">.

Comment: Or except for getting tmp_name value, is there any other better approach ? Thank you very much !